# Lose In Ranking During migration

Tags: seo, google

Hi I have a very old website, with a country level tld, for example - xyz.us. I then migrated the told to .com, which became - xyz.com. 
But after doing this I lost all the rankings in a week (also DA was very lower).
Is google considering the domain with .com tld as new?

Comment: When you changed the domain, did you do a 301 permanent redirect from all your old ranking URLs and had the on-page keywords and content optimized?

Comment: Yes, everything I checked. I feel google is considering it as new domain, earlier my da was 31 now its 17 (although increased from 4). backlink was 3,666 now it's 350. can this be the reason?

Comment: Did you also do the "Change of Domain" in GSC?